# JEST late test case affects previous test case

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

I'm writing a unit test to check if a certain section would appear if a related button is clicked

An I have this piece of code

```
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll("section")];
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll("button")];

const showRelatedSection = (buttonID) => {
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    if (section.id === buttonID) {
      section.removeAttribute("hidden");
    } else {
      section.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
    }
  })
};

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    showRelatedSection(button.id);
  });
});

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length);
const randomButton = buttons[randomIndex];

describe('click a random button', () => {
  randomButton.click();
  
  test('related section is shown', () => {
    const section = sections.find(s => s.id === randomButton.id);
    expect(section.hasAttribute("hidden")).toBeFalsy();
  });
});

describe('click another random button', () => {
  const restSections = sections;
  restSections.splice(randomIndex, 1);

  const anotherRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * restSections.length);
  const anotherRandomButton = restSections[anotherRandomIndex];
  
  anotherRandomButton.click();
  
  test('previous section is hidden', () => {
    const section = sections.find(s => s.id === randomButton.id);
    expect(section.hasAttribute("hidden")).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
  test('new related section is shown', () => {
    const section = sections.find(s => s.id === anotherRandomButton.id);
    expect(section.hasAttribute("hidden")).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

If I only ran 'click a random button' test it would pass, and 'related section is shown' would return false as expected.

but if I ran the whole test, the 'click another random button' would pass, but 'click a random button' would fail and 'related section is shown' would return true instead of false.

So, it seems that when I ran the whole test, the 'related section is shown' cannot check the test against the array of sections in that moment, and instead it checks the test against the array of sections from the late describe block.

How can I make the whole test pass?

Comment: `const restSections = sections;` isn't a deep copy so `.splice()` permanently modifies the array. Try fixing that... but also, please use `beforeEach` and totally tear down and re-build state before each test, because a lot of the code here looks highly suspicious. Tests should be idempotent and not mess with shared/global state in any way. They should be executable in any order.

Comment: Clicks are also permanent mutations on shared state. Bad news.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen for your comments, can you please explain what do mean by "highly suspicious code"?

Comment: As I mentioned, there cannot be shared state between tests but you have shared globals here, which is highly suspicious. The thing about sharing is it's not always obvious, so err on the side of normal unit test setup/teardown. Use a `beforeEach` and reinitialize all state before each test, including the document itself to the fullest extent possible so each assertion/`it` block is fully self-contained and idempotent. I don't have your document as a [mcve] so I can't really provide a complete answer.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen for the explanation, I'm working on the shared state issue, but I figured out that triggering click method of `anotherRandomButton` directly in the second `describe` is what caused that problem for me, I put it in a test case and the test suite is passed! I got the hint from [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#order-of-execution) where it written "Jest executes all describe handlers in a test file before it executes any of the actual tests".

Comment: Yes, that code belongs in `beforeEach` blocks.